# Confused about LLVM Arrays

Tags: llvm

I'm kind of confused on what are the steps to create, store and get values from LLVM arrays, so far I'm creating it with:

```
auto type = llvm::ArrayType::get(<TYPE>, <SOME_UINT>);
auto array = builder.CreateAlloca(type);
```

With that, I tried to get llvm::InBoundGEP to each element and store llvm::Value's to them, but that didn't worked...

Is there some guide for doing this?

Comment: Please include specifically what you tried, and specifically in what way it didn't work.

Comment: Well, thats the thing, I don't really know what to do, how can I get a pointer to an element of the array?, and after that read/store to it?

Comment: for arraytype and load using extractelement see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637803/accessing-elements-in-llvm-arrays and for GetElementPointer you can go through http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html

Answer (score 6):

Well, today I discovered the llc -march=cpp tool and actually helped me a lot, so I will answer here what I did in the end:

create the array (for that we need the type first):

```
auto arrayType = llvm::ArrayType::get(llvm::IntegerType::get(context, 32), size);
auto arrayPtr = new llvm::AllocaInst(arrayType, "", block);
```

now we will store some values to the array, for that we need to integers (read the GetElementPtr manual to know that each of them do), the second integer will tell the index (as in array[index]):

```
auto zero = llvm::ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(64, 0, true));
auto index = llvm::ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(32, INDEX, true));
```

now we can point to the element in the array and store something to it, (we will store the same index as in array[index] = index):

```
auto ptr = llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create(arrayPtr, { zero, index }, "", block);
auto store = new llvm::StoreInst(index, ptr, false, block);
```

Do that for each element of the array.

Now to load, assuming you have a llvm::Value as the index (which was my case, and ExtractElementInst didn't handle that, as far as I know at least...):

first get a ptr to the element (just like before):

```
ptr = llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create(arrayPtr, { zero, index }, "", block);
```

And load the value to some variable:

```
auto value = builder.CreateLoad(ptr);
```

---

There's a thing I learnt, you cannot easily create variable-length arrays, you will have to use some stack tricks I don't actually know how to use just yet, but if you wanna know, here are the instructions to use: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#llvm-stacksave-intrinsic

Try compiling this simple code:

int n = 5;
int array[n];

with `clang -S -llvm-emit your-file.c`

And you will see those instructions.

Comment: If someone finds something weird about the code please let me know, I'm learning here, any feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Amazing explanation, you fixed my core dumb, I had a mistake on the array of indexes because I did understand the semantics. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

following #Shello 's code i've been using it also for GlobalVariable arrays:

```
Value *index_pointer(GlobalVariable *array, Value *index) {
  return Builder.CreateGEP(
    array, {ConstantInt::get(Context, APInt(64, 0, true)), index}, "tmp");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me, inspired by @Shelo's answer:

```
// The values we want to create an array of
int integers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// Create llvm constants
std::vector<llvm::Value *> values;
for (int i : integers) {
    Value * value = ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(32, i, true));
    values.push_back(value);
}

// Get type of element and create array-type
Type * type = values[0]->getType();
auto arrayType = llvm::ArrayType::get(type, values.size());

// Create the alloca and zero index
AllocaInst *alloca = Builder.CreateAlloca(arrayType);
auto zero = ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(32, 0, true));

// Foreach value, create the corresponding index as a Value, create a GEP and store.
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    auto index = ConstantInt::get(context, llvm::APInt(32, i, true));
    auto ptr = Builder.CreateGEP(alloca, { zero, index });
    Builder.CreateStore(values[i], ptr);
}
// Do something with alloca
```